# How to make this Vue Composable for Firebase Storage awaitable?

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js

I'm trying to create a composable in my Vue TypeScript project that uploads something to Firebase 9 Storage and returns the url.

Currently having two problems:

1. When calling the `uploadImage` function I want it to be "awaitable" so I can wait for the storage url before continuing. But I'm not sure how to configure the composable to make that happen.
2. I'm getting this Eslint error I would like to resolve on the `uploadTask` success callback: `Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.`

Most of the code is a modified version of this [Firebase code example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress).

This is the calling function:

```
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';
import useStorage from 'src/composables/useStorage';

const { url, uploadImage } = useStorage();    
const profilePicFile: Ref<File | null> = ref(null);

const handleProfilePicUpdate = async () => {
  if (profilePicFile.value) {
    await uploadImage(profilePicFile.value); // <-- Calling the "uploadImage" composable here. But the "await" is currently uselss.
    profilePicUrl.value = url.value;
    userStore.setPhotoURL(profilePicUrl.value);
  }
};
```

This is the composable:

```
import {
  ref as storageRef,
  uploadBytesResumable,
  getDownloadURL,
} from 'firebase/storage';
import { store } from 'src/firebase/config';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import getUser from './getUser';
import { uid } from 'quasar';

const { user } = getUser();

const useStorage = () => {
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);
  const url = ref<string | null>(null);
  const progress = ref<number | null>(null);

  const uploadImage = async (file: File) => { // <-- Marked the function as async, but I'm not sure which part should be awaited. Or failing that, maybe I should shomehow make the function return a promise with the url?
    if (user.value) {
      const filePath = `user_images/${user.value.uid}/${
        file.name + '_' + uid()
      }`;
      const storageReference = storageRef(store, filePath);
      try {
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageReference, file);
        uploadTask.on(
          'state_changed',
          // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
          (snapshot) => {
            progress.value =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          },
          // Handle unsuccessful uploads
          (err) => {
            if (err instanceof Error) {
              console.log(err.message);
              error.value = err.message;
            } else {
              throw err;
            }
          },
          // Handle successful uploads
          async () => { // <-- Eslint error on this entire function
            try {
              url.value = await getDownloadURL(storageReference);
            } catch (err) {
              if (err instanceof Error) {
                console.log(err.message);
                error.value = err.message;
              } else {
                throw err;
              }
            }
          }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
          console.log(err.message);
          error.value = err.message;
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return { url, error, progress, uploadImage };
};

export default useStorage;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the ESLint issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is caused by the fact that `uploadImage()` does not actually `await` anything at the "top level" of the function. While the function does call [`uploadBytesResumable()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadbytesresumable), passing `async`/`await` arguments, the result of the call itself (an [`UploadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadtask.md#uploadtask_interface)) is not `await`-ed, which leads to the problem you observed.

To make `uploadImage()` pause for the upload, you can either 1️⃣ `await` the `UploadTask` result, or 2️⃣ return the `UploadTask` itself:

```js
const uploadImage = async (file: File) => {
  if (user.value) {
    ⋮
    try {
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageReference, file)
      uploadTask.on(⋯)

      await uploadTask 1️⃣
      // or...
      return uploadTask 2️⃣
    }
  }
}
```

The difference is the latter allows the caller access to the Firebase snapshot data:

```js
const snapshot = await uploadImage()
```